# How to check if there are two concatenated methods with regex?

Tags: java, regex

What is the best way to check, if there are any lines with two methods concatenated? In my case between .where(*) and .first, .last, .single
For example,
I want to get: foo.where(smth).first()
But not: foo.where(smth).bar().first()
So if there two concatenated methods (.where with .first or .last or .single), I want get this line.

I've tried to make regex for it: .where(.*?).(first|last|single)
https://regex101.com/r/3a7SpE/1

But, as I understood, back tracking makes foo.where(smth).bar().first() also "correct".

What should I change to make this works, please?

Comment: Try `\.where\([^()]*?\)\.(?:first|last|single)`, but if the text inside parentheses can contain `(` or `)`, the task becomes much harder. Do you need to match specific grammar?

Comment: Thanks, it got better. But unfortunately, another method is possible in .where(), and text inside parentheses could contain other parentheses..

Comment: Do you think matching any amount of nested paired parentheses will work for you? What is the programming language?

Comment: I guess yes. As test case I use: a.where(x -> x.getName() != "something").first()
Programming language is Java.

Comment: Ok, so, regex is not an option.

Comment: Oh... Okay, thanks for you help!